# Работа с Gulp проектом на разных ПК

Tags: gulp, package

При переносе `Gulp`-проекта с одного ПК на другой, нужно ли заново устанавливать все необходимые пакеты?

Comment: Естественно. Нужно установить все зависимости из package.json

Answer (score 1):

В `package.json` в корне проекта нужно прописать все зависимости вашего приложения. Тогда на другом компьютере достаточно будет стянуть репозиторий и установить все необходимые пакеты командой `npm i`.